# Getting Image from URL/server

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsurlconnection

I'm fairly new to iPhone development and trying to fetch  'Images from Server' in my application.

I'm using the following method to do this:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromURLString:(NSString *)urlString 
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request          
    returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    [request release];
    [self handleError:error];
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)result];

    NSLog(@"urlString: %@",urlString);
    return resultImage;
}
```

This function does not return the expected image although I can see in debugger that NSData for the Image object has some value (in bytes)

Although,  a very similar function for getting text from server works and I get expected values.

```
- (NSString *)jsonFromURLString:(NSString *)urlString
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
    returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    [request release];
    [self handleError:error];
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return [resultString autorelease];
}
```

This method works fine.

Could someone  please help me in understanding why I'm not getting the Image from server?

Thanks

Answer (score 28):

If all you are trying to do is grab an image from a web server via a URL there is an easier way.

This is what I use:

```
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: 
    [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
    [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/image.jpg"]]];
```

And if you want to use it on an image view just do the following:

```
// Let's assume the picture is an instantiated UIImageView
[picture setImage: myImage];
[myImage release];
```

I'm sure there are reasons why a person might not want to use this approach, but I would start with this and see if it will do what you need it to.

Comment: As long as you put it in a separate thread so the UI doesn't lock up.

Comment: Why do you release myImage? You haven't allocated it

Answer (score 2):

I've written RemoteImage class to load images over the network asynchronously. It also takes care of freeing the memory when necessary. See this post: http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2009/11/remote-image-for-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that you're not actually fetching an image, or you are fetching an image that iPhone can't decode. I would start by checking the MIME type of the result (`[response MIMEType]`) and make sure it's what you're expecting and not actually a string for instance. Then make sure that your type is one of the types [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can handle: tiff, jpeg, gif, png, bmp, ico, cur, xbm.

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be that what your server're returning isn't actually image data, and you can just paste the url into a browser and see if you get the image.  There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code except for the lack of error-checking.

When you pass a non-image NSData into a +imageWithData message, you will get nil.  You should probably check for that.

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't directly relevant to your question, but I did want to point out that your error checking here has a potential issue. Methods like this that have a reference parameter to an `NSError` generally do not define what they return on success. In other words, you should check the methods return value first, and *only* access the error pointer if the method failed:

```
NSString *resultString = nil;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                       returningResponse:&response
                                                   error:&error];
[request release];

if( result ) {
  resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
else {
  [self handleError:error];
}
```